# PE File format got wrong in AddressOfEntryPoint?

Tags: portable-executable

I go through the book: "Malware Data Science Attack Detection and Attribution" in chapter one and use pefile python module to check the AddressOfEntryPoint, 
 I found the sample: ircbot.exe's AddressOfEntryPoint is 0xCC00FFEE when I do pe.dump_info(). This value is quite large and look wrong.

[ircbot.exe's OPTIONAL Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5ez7.png)
md5: 17fa7ec63b129f171511a9f96f90d0d6

how to fix this AddressOfEntryPoint?

Comment: I put ircbot.exe in IDA Pro and check one function by one, and finally find the real entry point should be 0x417b00,   0x417b00 = 0x400000 (ImageBase) + 0x001000 (BaseOfCode) + 0x016b00 .  also try to figure how the 0x016b00 is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is "normal". When you download the samples from the URL [malwaredatascience.com/code-and-data](http://malwaredatascience.com/code-and-data) of the book, the name of the downloaded ZIP file is **malware_data_science_entrypoints_edited.zip**. As mentioned at page 221 of the book, this has been done on purpose by the authors to "disable it from executing."

Answer (score 0):

Based on @user5742815's comment, I updated the code with the real address of the entrypoint. The updated script below produces the same output as the one in the book:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pefile
from capstone import *

# load the target PE file
pe = pefile.PE("ircbot.exe")

# get the address of the program entry point from the program header
# entrypoint = pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.AddressOfEntryPoint
# see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810422/pe-file-format-got-wrong-in-addressofentrypoint
entrypoint = 0x0017b00

# compute memory address where the entry code will be loaded into memory
entrypoint_address = entrypoint+pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.ImageBase

# get the binary code from the PE file object
binary_code = pe.get_memory_mapped_image()[entrypoint:entrypoint+100]

# initialize disassembler to disassemble 32 bit x86 binary code
disassembler = Cs(CS_ARCH_X86, CS_MODE_32)

# disassemble the code
for instruction in disassembler.disasm(binary_code, entrypoint_address):
    print "%s\t%s" %(instruction.mnemonic, instruction.op_str)
```